# "Broadcasting" a hostname to a network

Tags: networking, hosts-file, hostname

When I `nmap` my home network (here on a portion of the subnet), I see the following:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.aaa
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.bbb
Host is up (0.029s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap scan report for hostname1 (192.168.0.ccc)
Host is up (0.21s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap scan report for hostname2 (192.168.0.ddd)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

In the given example, `192.168.0.aaa` and `192.168.0.ccc` are two interfaces on a single device, likewise for `.bbb` and `.ccc`. The `ccc` and `ddd` represent WiFi cards assigned IPs via DHCP, whereas `aaa` and `bbb` are direct Ethernet cable connections on static IPs. The former broadcasts the hostname, but the latter does not. I intend to disable the wireless interfaces shortly.

It is convenient for me to see hostnames in the router, via `nmap`, and in other places rather than referring to these devices strictly as their IPs. I understand I could set up a DNS server for this purpose, but am not quite there yet.

How might I enable "broadcast" of the hostname?

Comment: well, in terms of sources for name information, DNS and host files entries are sure to work, but are not automatic, unless you set up some form of Dynamic DNS. Windows hosts exchange name information when participating in a workgroup, but most modern laptops would need configuration to enable those features on the network. I'm not even sure if nmap would attempt to find hostnames via SMB. a WINS server might be the most reliable bet, but then both the clients and servers would need configuration. Just about any way you go, ddns is about the only fully automatic option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers in a network don't "broadcast" their hostname. What happens in your setup is very likely that whoever assigns your `ccc` and `ddd` (BTW, `192.168.*.*` is a private subnet, so you can use the full address; no need to keep these IPs secret) address via DHCP also acts as an DNS server, which includes the ability to do reverse lookups.

So when nmap scans `192.168.0.ccc`, it does a reverse DNS lookup of `192.168.0.ccc`, and the DNS server answers with `hostname1`.

You didn't say where `aaa` and `bbb` connect to, but as they also have `192.168.0.*` addresses, that means you intend them to be in the same subnet controlled by the DHCP and DNS server for `ccc` and `ddd`, which means that server should also get name entries for them (if it's a home router, often you can configure static addresses with names).

Comment: “Computers in a network don't "broadcast" their hostname.” – But they do, well, can. It’s called Multicast DNS. The `.local` TLD is reserved for mDNS.